# Exibição fora de ordem esperada

Tags: javascript, jquery

Estou enviando requisições, só que esse retorno vem em uma ordem inesperada.

Eu preciso que a garantia de update venha primeiro que o suporte e consultoria.

Tem hora que dá certo, tem hora que não.

**Retorno inesperado**

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

**Retorno esperado**

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

```js
function requisicaoSincrona(categoria, modulo, destino, callback) {
 var xmlhttp = null;
 if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
  // code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
  xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
 } else {
  // code for IE6, IE5
  xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject('Microsoft.XMLHTTP');
 }
 var values = {
  modulo: modulo,
  categoria: categoria
 };
 var myJsonString = JSON.stringify(values);
 xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = respond;

 xmlhttp.open('POST', 'classes/getData.php', true);
 xmlhttp.send(myJsonString);
 //xmlhttp.abort();
 //como o código executado na volta da requisição é a função respond, chamamos o callback aqui
 function respond() {
  if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
   destino.innerHTML += xmlhttp.responseText;
  }
  //verifica se uma função foi de fato passada, para então chama-la
  if (callback) callback.call();
 }
}
var x = document.getElementsByClassName('terceiraEtapa')[0];
requisicaoSincrona(6, modulo, x, function() {
 requisicaoSincrona(9, modulo, x);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Creio que seu problema seja apenas a requisição assíncrona, que é o padrão para os navegadores. [Explicação](http://www.diogomatheus.com.br/blog/php/requisicoes-sincronas-e-assincronas/)

Se mudar a terceira entrada da próxima linha de código para FALSE, creio que vai obter o resultado esperado sempre, porém não afirmo que seja a melhor solução.

```
xmlhttp.open('POST', 'classes/getData.php', true);
```

Eu tentaria retornar ambas as estruturas HTML na mesma requisição para o arquivo getData.php.